# select average from average

Tags: mysql, average

I have the following table:

```
rating
--------
| id | account_id | room | kitchen | bathroom |
-----------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1          | 5    | 5       | 5        |
| 2  | 1          | 2    | 4       | 1        |
| 3  | 1          | 5    | 2       | 1        |
-----------------------------------------------
```

People can rate the room, kitchen and bathroom (from 1-5).

Average rating for ID = 1: 5 (because 15/3 = 5)

Average rating for ID = 2: 2.3333 (because 7/3 = 2.33333)

Average rating for ID = 3: 2.6666 (because 8/3 = 2.66665)

**First question**

As you can see, the average rating for ID = 2 => 2.3333... and for ID = 3 => 2.6666. How can I make it floor() and ceil()? (when < .5 => floor, when > .5 => ceil), so that the avg rating for ID = 2 becomes 2 (instead of 2.3333) and the avg rating for ID = 3 becomes 3 (instead of 2.6666...)

**Second question**

I want to select the average rating of the average ratings (so the average rating from all the rows together). So - when floor() and ceil() are used I have 3 average ratings: 5, 2 and 3 => 10/15 => 3. How do I get to the 3?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. See normalization

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, the answer is [`round()`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-round-function.php):

```
select round( (room + kitchen + bathroom) / 3)
```

For the second, you would just use aggregation:

```
select avg(room + kitchen + bathroom)
from ratings;
```

If you want the average of the rounded results:

```
select round(avg(round(room + kitchen + bathroom)))
from ratings;
```

However, that seems strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`ROUND`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round)** function.

**Query**

```
SELECT id, ROUND(((room + kitchen + bathroom)/3), 0) as `average`
FROM rating
GROUP BY id;
```